# Criando table com column de ID primary key com auto incremento

Tags: sql-server

Eu estou usando o `SQL Server Management` e estou tentando criar 
uma table que possui o campo de `ID` que deve ser auto incrementado.
Entretanto, não posso usar a propriedade `IDENTITY`, e sim fazer tudo no `script`, na mão mesmo.

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer isso, já que (por exemplo) assim não funciona (pois é para o MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Comment: Não entendi, vc quer q ele seja `Identity` ou quer criar algo para acrescentar o valor de acordo com uma regra especial?

Comment: Eu quero fazer a propriedade identity "a mão", sem usar a propriedade propriamente dita, e sim programar o que ela faz. Eu teria que usar create table e alter table, talvez? Não sei ao certo pois sou iniciante em banco de dados

Comment: Sem usar o autoincremento fornecido pelo banco você precisaria controlar essa criação de ID dentro da sua aplicação.

Comment: @MarcellAlves não necessariamente, vc pode fazer isso via banco tb

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida, como ele poderia fazer via banco? Poste uma resposta com essa solução, pois é o que o usuário está precisando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução para esse problema é criar uma function que ira te retornar o próximo valor de sua PK, segue um exemplo abaixo como se fosse uma `Identity` que acrescenta o valor de 1 em 1

**Tabela**

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

**Função para gerar sua Identity customizada**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ProximoIdPersons() 
RETURNS int 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @lastval int 
    SET @lastval = (select max(ID) from Persons) 
    IF @lastval is null SET @lastval = 0
    return @lastval + 1
END
```

**Insert que você executaria**

```
INSERT INTO Persons (ID, LastName, FirstName, Age)
VALUES (dbo.ProximoIdPersons(),'Almeida', 'Jeferson', 27)
```

Comment: No caso essa "Create function" eu crio em outra query?

Comment: @Bellon pode ser em outra query, isso vc só vai executar uma vez, ele vai criar uma função no seu banco de dados e você depois vai poder utilizar essa função

Comment: Ah, entendi! Muito obrigado, vou testar

Comment: ID e Persons não está sendo reconhecido, o que pode ser?

Comment: @Bellon em qual trecho ele não está sendo reconhecido, vc criou a tabela antes de tentar criar a função e fazer o insert?

Answer (score 1):

O script de criação para SQL Server ficaria assim:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Persons
    (
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255) NULL,
    Age int NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Persons ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_Persons PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    ID
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Persons SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```

Comment: É que o objetivo é fazer a propriedade identity "a mão".